# Can we change the order of the group in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-8.5

i am grouping the record by ordercode which is integer value as ascending order. But ordercode have zero(0) as one of the value.
when i am grouping records by ordercode, it starts withs zero group as first. but i dont want to show zero group as first.
can we do like order should be ascending order of ordercode except zero group and i want zero group at the end of the report?

Comment: You should tag your question once with `crystal-reports`, then a second time with the specific version of the product that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Create a formula field that will result in the sorting that you desire, then group the formula field.

For example:

```
If {table.order_code}=0 Then
  1000000000
Else
  {table.order_code}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Specified order` where you can specify as required or if you need 0 as the last group why don't you group `descending order.`

Comment: i can use "Specified order" but i am not sure how many value does client have.(example if i specify order as 1,2,0 but if client have records from 1 to 10 then 1,2,0 then i dont know what happens). client want those data in ascending order only. Do you have any other idea, please share. thanks